# Check the series for convergence, sin, binomial coefficient

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Could you tell me how to check if the following series are convergent (including radius of convergence)?

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sin\left(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 1}\right)z^n,$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \binom{2n}{n}z^n,$$

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^n + (-2)^n}{n} \cdot (z+1)^n.$$

If $z =x+ iy$ is a complex variable, then there exists a certain circle (circle of convergence) $|z - z_0 |<R$ with center at the point $z = z_0$ , inside which power series converges
absolutely; for $|z - z_0 |>R$ the series diverges. At points lying on the circumference
of the circle of convergence, power series series  may both converge and
diverge.

Comment: I think the term your looking for is radius of convergence. You should probably fix the indexes in your sums too, and define convergence when $z$ isn't specified.

Comment: If $z$ hasn't been specified how can we determine if it converges the second one would very well converge if say $z=\frac{1}{3}$, but would clearly diverge if $z=3$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**
Find the radius of convergence for 1) and 3) by
$$R=\dfrac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{|a_n|}}}$$
and  for 2)  by $$R=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\left|\dfrac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|.$$
**Added:**
Then 
$$R_1=\dfrac{1}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{|\sin{(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 1})}|}}}=1, \\
R_2=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot\dfrac{((n+1)!)^2}{(2n+2)!}}=\dfrac{1}{4}, \\
R_3=\dfrac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n + (-2)^n}{n}}}}=\dfrac{1}{\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[2n]{3^{2n} + (-2)^{2n}}}}=\dfrac{3}{\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[2n]{1 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2n}}}}=\dfrac{1}{3}.
$$
Examine the convergence of the first series on the circle $|z|=R_1$ and denote $z=R_1e^{i\varphi}=e^{i\varphi}.$ Then
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin{(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 1})}}e^{in\varphi}$$
where $\varphi\in[0,\,2\pi).$
Rewrite $\sin$ terms:
$$\sin{(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 1})}=\sin{(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 1}-n\pi+n\pi)}=(-1)^n \sin{(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 1}-n\pi)}=(-1)^n \sin{\dfrac{\pi(n^2 + 1-n^2 )}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}+n}}=(-1)^n \sin{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}+n}}$$
Thus the series takes the form
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{(-1)^n \sin{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}+n}}}\,e^{in\varphi}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}+n}}\,e^{in(\varphi-\pi)}} $$ 
and for $\varphi\ne \pi$ is convergent by the Dirichlet's test.
If $\varphi= \pi,$ we have the series
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}+n}}} $$ which is divergent since
$$\sin{\dfrac{\pi}{\sqrt{n^2 + 1}+n}}\sim \dfrac{\pi}{2n},\quad n\to\infty.$$
For the second series $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot\dfrac{e^{in\varphi}}{4^n}} $$
using the Stirling's formula $$n!\sim{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\dfrac{n}{e} \right)^n}, \quad {n\to{\infty}}$$ we have that 
$$\dfrac{(2n)!}{4^n(n!)^2}\sim\dfrac{\sqrt{4\pi n}\cdot\left(\dfrac{2n}{e} \right)^{2n}}{4^n \cdot{2\pi n}\cdot \left(\dfrac{n}{e} \right)^{2n} }=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\pi n}},$$ 
so this series is convergent by the Dirichlet's test for $\varphi\ne{0}$ and diverges if $\varphi={0}.$
The third series becomes to
$$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{{\dfrac{3^n + (-2)^n}{n}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{in\varphi}}{3^n}}=\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{{\dfrac{1 + \left(-\dfrac{2}{3}\right)^n}{n}}{e^{in\varphi}}}.$$
Can you apply  the Dirichlet's test  yourself?

Comment: For the first one I got $R=\frac{1}{|z|}$, for the third $R=\frac{1}{4|z|}$, but I have problems estimating $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n + (-2)^n}{n}}} $

Comment: Note that $a_n$ are _coefficients_ at $(z-z_0)^n,$ thus $R$ is not depending on $z.$ Next, using the well-known limit $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{n}}=1,$ we have $\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[n]{\frac{3^n + (-2)^n}{n}}}=\limsup\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[2n]{3^{2n} + (-2)^{2n}}}=3\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}{\sqrt[2n]{1 + \left(\frac{2}{3}\right)^{2n}}}=3$

Comment: Thank you. Could you tell me how to determine convergence at the points on the circles?

Comment: Denote $z-z_0=Re^{i\varphi}$ and check the convergence of the series  
$$ \sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\sin{(\pi \sqrt{n^2 + 1})}}e^{in\varphi}, \qquad (R = 1,\;\;z_0=0)\\
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)}\cdot\dfrac{e^{in\varphi}}{4^n}} , \qquad \left(R = \dfrac{1}{4} ,\;\;z_0=0\right)\\
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{{\dfrac{3^n + (-2)^n}{n}}\cdot\dfrac{e^{in\varphi}}{3^n}}, \qquad \left(R = \dfrac{1}{3},\;\;z_0=-1\right)
$$

Comment: Could you tell me how to test convergence of those series? Can I use the same tests as above? What does $\varphi$ mean?

Comment: 1) In the previous comment I made a typo. Should be $$\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}{\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}\cdot\dfrac{e^{in\varphi}}{4^n}}$$ 2) I add some details to the answer.

Comment: I've been trying to determine convergence of the remaining two series, but I am not getting anywhere. Could you help me a bit more? I think that since $\dfrac{(2n)!}{(n!)^2}$ diverges, then $\dfrac{e^{in\varphi}}{4^n‌​}$ should be convergent to $0$.

Comment: Could we use $e^{in \varphi} = (\cos \varphi + i \sin \varphi)^n$?

Comment: Yes, but it is more complicative

Comment: Thanks a lot. I really appreciate it.

Comment: You are welcome:)